# Spring SAML extension, how to set the relayState?

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I have a Spring boot application which performs the authentication for several applications, and I would like to set the RelayState so that after authentication the application redirects back to the calling application.

Within my configure method, I'm connecting to the IDP using:
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .apply(saml())
            .serviceProvider()
                .keyStore()
                    .storeFilePath(this.keyStoreFilePath)
                    .password(this.password)
                    .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                    .keyPassword(this.password)
                    .and()
                .protocol("https")
                .hostname(String.format("%s", this.serverName))
                .basePath(this.contextPath)
                .and()
            .identityProvider()
            .discoveryEnabled(false)
            .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);

Does anyone have any examples on how to set the relay state?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for setting the relayState parameter? I'm facing the same problem.